# Use of different malloc implementations for Eneas OSE?

Tags: embedded, malloc, ose

I've heard that Enea's OSE's malloc implementation is not very effective - does anyone know if they use some standard malloc like ptmalloc2?

I Would be interested if anyone have managed to achieve better results by porting some other malloc to Enea's OSE.

Comment: What does "not very effective" mean?  Or "better results" for that matter?  You need to be clear about what problem you are trying to solve - it may be a non-problem in your application.  You've "heard" something, but that is by definition *hearsay* where is the documentary or impirical evidence?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problems with `malloc()` in any real-time multi-threaded system are non-deterministic behaviour, and thread safety.

One would imagine that the OSE implementation is at least thread-safe.  Non-deterministic allocation time can be dealt with by not allocating in real-time critical code (such as during initialisation, or only in non-critical background threads for example).

Many RTOS libraries supply a malloc implementation for reasons of thread safety, but equally many standard library implementations for embedded systems provide mutex stubs so that the standard library implementation can be made thread safe too.  Check your library's documentation on thread-safety.

To solve the problem of non-determinism in real-time critical code, you could use a fixed-block allocator.  OSE may provide that directly, but it is easily implemented by preallocating (dynamically or statically) blocks of memory and placing a pointer to each block on a queue.  To allocate a block you simply take a pointer from the queue, and to free it you place the pointer back on the queue. If the queue is empty, you have run out of memory.  Multiple queues, each holding different sized blocks will improve memory usage and avoid "wastage" to some extent.

Comment: Not really answering my question, but thanks anyway. OSE has a more deterministic memory allocation as well which I am already aware of. But for some reasons I am more interested in the standard malloc implementation at the moment.

Comment: @user1147851:  I realise it is not a direct answer, but as mentioned in my comment to the question, you have not been particularly clear with respect to the problem you are trying to solve and the results you need.  You might get a better answer if you improve the question by addressing questions in my comment.  If you choose not to address these deficiencies, you are not really helping yourself.